# create rdf files based on SKOS data model in python

Tags: python, rdf

I want to create a .rdf file containing data in the form of SKOS model and written in RDF/XML format. I prefer using Python language. Can you suggest any good python libraries? If possible, a simple example would be of great help.
thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at [RDFLib](https://pypi.org/project/rdflib/):

> RDFLib is a Python library for working
> with RDF, a simple yet powerful
> language for representing information.
>
> The library contains parsers and
> serializers for RDF/XML, N3, NTriples,
> Turtle, TriX and RDFa. The library
> presents a Graph interface which can
> be backed by any one of a number of
> store implementations, including,
> memory, MySQL, Redland, SQLite,
> Sleepycat, ZODB and SQLObject.

---

**Edited to add:** Here is an example producing sample SKOS output:

```
from rdflib import Graph, Literal, Namespace, RDF, URIRef

graph = Graph()
skos = Namespace('http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#')
graph.bind('skos', skos)

graph.add((URIRef('URI'), RDF['type'], skos['Concept']))
graph.add((URIRef('URI'), skos['prefLabel'], Literal('Temp', lang='en')))
graph.add((URIRef('URI'), skos['related'], URIRef('URI-Related')))

print(graph.serialize(format='pretty-xml'))
```

Here's the output:

```
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'
  xmlns:skos='http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#'
>
  <skos:Concept rdf:about="URI">
    <skos:related rdf:resource="URI-Related"/>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Temp</skos:prefLabel>
  </skos:Concept>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: RDFLib does not support SKOS format right? I want the output like the following:  
  
    <skos:Concept rdf:about="URI">  
        <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Temp</skos:prefLabel>  
        <skos:related rdf:resource="URI-related"/>  
    </skos:Concept>

Comment: @parin, what do you mean by "support" for SKOS format? Edited the answer to add some example code demonstrating how to produce your desired output.

Comment: thank you for the answer. This is exactly what I wanted. Sorry for writing such an unclear comment.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these links will help?

- http://librdf.org/docs/python.html
- http://infomesh.net/pyrple/